# Difference between tatami mat counters 帖 and 畳

Tags: usage, counters, word-usage

What is the difference between tatami mat counters 帖 and 畳 (both pronounced じょう)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

畳 is used only for tatami and is included in the Joyo list. 帖 can be used for folding screens, stage curtains, [shields](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:Ashigaru_using_shields_%28tate%29.jpg), batches of nori seaweed, batches of Washi (traditional paper), or traditional books as well as tatami, and is not included in the Joyo list.

帖 is often used as the counter for tatami mats when describing room size on a floor plan.

[image]

Comment: @Ambo100 I have approved your edit for now, although I would ask @ marasai to review it and [roll back](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/12470/revisions) if necessary. The edit could also have been submitted as a separate answer, or as a comment on this answer instead.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Thank you, I wasn't sure if it was adding enough for it to be its own answer.

Comment: @Ambo100 It is always fine to have multiple answers — it is usually not helpful to simply repeat content of an existing answer, but adding an answer to complement an existing answer is always welcome (as long as it is relevant to the question of course).